# How to finish screen capture using MediaProjectionManager?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, screen-capture

I started screen capture intent according to [MediaProjectionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()):

```
var intent = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

... but I have no idea how to stop screen capture. Sample projects for API 21 are still not available.

Answer (score 2):

ok, found solution, firstly save result to [MediaProjection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) instance:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
super<Activity>.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

and to stop simply execute:

```
mediaProjection.stop()
```

Comment: can you tell, and where is the video file being stored?

Comment: Can you start it again later?  Or do you need a new MediaProjection?